# How can I maintain a users position in a listview when images dynamically load above the current position?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a feed type app with multiple news items,

- News items are ordered with the oldest item on top and newest item at the bottom (the reverse of what you would see with twitter for example)
- News items are arranged in a `Listview.builder`
- Each news item has a variable number of images associated with them
- Each image is of variable height

| Old news item(s) |
| --- |
| Image 1 |
| Image 2 |
| image 3 |
| Image 4 |
| Image 5 |

| Unread news item |
| --- |
|  |

| New news item(s) |
| --- |
| Image 1 |
| Image 2 |
| image 3 |

- When the feed first opens, the app automatically scrolls to the first unread news item using a scrollable-ensurevisible

```
scrollController.position.ensureVisible(
            unreadnewsitemKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()!,
            alignment: 1,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            curve: Curves.linear
        );
```

#### **The problem:**

The automatic scroll works flawlessly, however because of slow network connections/cellular connections, the images part of the `Old news item(s)` may load after the automatic scroll finishes.

When this happens, a content shift occurs, pushing the currently viewed `Unread news item` downwards, and the user loses their reading position.

#### **The question:**

Is there anyways to maintain the users current position in the listview no matter what images are loaded above the current position?  I am willing to change anything and everything about my app's structure except 1 thing.  Using a fixed size image height is not an option.  Image heights must remain variable to their true original dimensions

Comment: Do you own the data source for the images?

Comment: @DanHarms Image sizes are unknown and sources are from all over

Comment: Your only real option then is to add a listener to the images as they load and scroll after each load. I'd probably disable that once the user themselves scrolled, but they would still suffer from items jumping around. The correct way to handle this is set a strict height, but you've already said that's a no-go so you're going to have to live with the tradeoffs.

Comment: @DanHarms Yes it looks like it.  I wish there was a way to just have the listview grow upwards when content changes, then content would be pushed up instead of down

Comment: You could postpone image loading for older articles until visible. That would prevent the content from pushing it down.

Comment: @DanHarms Wouldn't that just delay the content shift, but that shift would be inevitable

Comment: It would maintain a top position, which I feel is what you really care about. It may push content within the visible space down further but your top item will be anchored.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting image width and height when you load the news to list? If yes, you can find the ratio of width/height and based on that you can calculate the position.

Comment: Unfortunately, the image sizes are unknown